# MS Access: How to bound text box of form with query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-office, ms-access-2010

I created a form in MS Access 2010 and added a textbox here. Then I created a simple query (for example `SELECT 10 AS studval;`) and tried to set in Properties (of textbox) -> Data -> Control Source this query, but I got error #Name?.

How do I fix this error?

All names of query, textbox, query return values are correct.  Or maybe are there any other ways to bound textbox and custom SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do it, but it is possible using the form's On Activate event.  First set up a query (Query1) with a single value called "studval" then open the form properties and add an Event Procedure for On Activate.  It should look like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Activate()

Dim myString As String

myString = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Query1").OpenRecordset.Fields("studval")
Me.Text0.SetFocus

[Text0].Text = myString

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Control Source of the form to the query rather than the control source of the text box.  A text box control source can only refer back to it's form's control source.

If you want just one text box bound to a query you have to create a subform linked to the parent form with that text box in it.